# Could I use a FD-M735 with a FC-MC3x?

Tags: crankset, compatibility, derailleur-front

I have a Shimano FD-M735 currently on my bike, and I would like to replace the aging FC-TY33 that I have, with a FC-M730 ideally, but they are too pricey. However, I have found a [FC-MC36](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SHIMANO-crankset-Fc-mc33-Fc-mc36-Welgo-Pedals/264272343749) and a [FC-MC34](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Shimano-STX-Vintage-Retro-Triple-Chainset-Cranks-FC-MC34-175mm-42T-32T-22T/202620826285) (42T/32T/22T) at a very reasonable price.

Is there any reason why the FD-M735 and the FC-MC34/36 shouldn't work together?

I have the old style XTII gear shifters:

[image: XTII gear shifter]

As an aside, I presume that the FC-MC34/36 is of lower spec/quality when compared to the FC-M730. Would that be a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why the XT derailleur would not work with the same generation SLX crankset.  The FD-M735 is a triple derailleur (used for a triple chainring crankset) with a total capacity of 26T.  Your proposed FC-MC34, having 42-32-22 tooth chainrings, doesn't surpass this limit so you're good there.  Looks like your derailleur could handle up to a 48T large ring.

As mentioned above, quality difference between the two is minimal as the Deore XT models (which is what the FC-M730 belongs to) sit just one tier above STX (FC-MC34/6's designation).  According to [this spec table](http://www.bikepro.com/products/shimano_tables/shim_frtchnwhl_table.html) the biggest difference is the XT has aluminum large chainring vs. STX's steel and there are also some differences in finish.  Note that the table doesn't include exactly the FC-M730 model, but references FC-M737/9.  I believe this is because the FC-MC34/6 is newer by a year or two than the M730, which grew into an M737.  At any rate, the two are about as close as it gets in a comparison.